# it is worth doing somethin = something is worth doing?

Tags: meaning

Is there a real difference between:

> 1 It is worth buying this phone. – 2 This phone is worth buying.

I heard an opinion that 1 is wrong. However, this is what I found in a dictionary.

> 3 It's worth discussing.

**So, technically 1 is correct.** Is there a semantic-related reason or something else that makes 1 incorrect?

On top of that, what’s the difference between.

> 4 It's worth discussing.
>
> 5 It's worthwhile discussing.

Comment: [***It's worth noting***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%27s+worth+noting%2CIt%27s+worth+to+note%2CIt%27s+worthwhile+noting%2CIt%27s+worthwhile+to+note&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) that only *that* version has any real currency. The three other permutations (with ***worthwhile*** and/or ***to try***) are all syntactically valid (and effectively, mean the same), but they're rarely used.

Comment: Note that idiomatic usage varies with adverbial elements like ***worth buying*** and, for example, ***easy to use***. So *This phone is easy to use / It's easy to use this phone / Using this phone is easy* are all fine, but *It's easy using this phone* is relatively uncommon, even though syntactically it looks pretty much like *It's worth buying this phone*.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that 1 is wrong: it's not the same as 3.

In example 3, *It's worth discussing.*, the word *it* refers to something previously mentioned, outside of the sentence.

In example 1, *it* tries to refer to *buying this phone*, at the end of the same sentence, and it doesn't work.

You could say *It's worthwhile buying this phone.*, which is a way of saying
*Buying this phone is worthwhile.*

But using *worth*, that transformation doesn't work:
**Buying this phone is worth.*

Adding to the previous answer. Here is a definition of *worth*:
[Merriam-Webster *worth*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worth)
**preposition**
2: deserving of
*well worth the effort*

So, *worth* is a preposition in this use. The M-W definition has an adjective sense, but it is marked as archaic, so it's irrelevant here.

Here is the definition of *worthwhile*:
[Merriam-Webster *worthwhile*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worthwhile)
**adjective**
1: being worth the time or effort spent
*worthwhile preparations*

Since *worth* is a preposition, it requires an object, which it lacks in example 1.
In the examples with *worthwhile*, as an adjective, it needs a noun or pronoun to apply to.

As to examples 4 and 5, I find 4 understandable - something previously mentioned is linked to the adjectival preposition phrase "worth discussing*.
Example 5 doesn't hold together for me - it wants a last word-
*It's worthwhile discussing prices.*
If, in example 5, *it* refers to something outside the sentence, then *discussing* seems to be hanging there unattached.

Comment: What is the difference between 4 and 5?

Comment: My take on that one - (4) means that it (the topic) is one that it would be useful to discuss; (5) means that discussing it would be a worthwhile activity - so, in effect, not much difference.

Comment: I can find lots of examples of "It's worth buying..." and "Is it worth buying...?" on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%27s+worth+buying%22), Twitter, etc, and I don't think you've shown why it might be wrong. It's probably colloquial rather than very formal, but still valid in that context.

Comment: "It's worth buying." What's worth buying? The phone is worth buying. But, "It's worth buying this phone." doesn't have any connection or use for the word "it".